# Fetching from cordova plugins registry failed: connect ETIMEDOUT from registry.cordova.io

Tags: cordova

(Using Cordova 6.0.0)

I have the following plugin definition in my config.xml:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="~1.1.0"/>
```

When I try to install my android platform, I receive the following error:

```
npm http GET http://registry.cordova.io/cordova-plugin-device
Fetching from npm failed: connect ETIMEDOUT
```

When I checked the website, it is indeed down - there's nothing there - and the cordova repository mentioned in the [documentation](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tutorial-cordova-5-readme/) is plugins.cordova.io.

What is the problem? Should I redirect the cordova repository somewhere else somehow?

Answer (score 3):

Update:
Cordova has moved their plugins to npm now. Check the below link:

http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/04/21/plugins-release-and-move-to-npm.html

Answer (score 1):

I did a workaround by entering the full github repository address eg: cordova plugin add "https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media". It also requires that git is installed with its environment variable set.

But when I do the "platform add" command it does look for registry.cordova.io

So another workaround was needed: 
I downloaded the git repo of the plugin on my local hard drive in a folder different than my cordova project.
In the repository of the plugin I edited the plugin.xml file by commenting all the tags repo and dependency as follow:

```
<!--repo>https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-compat.git</repo-->      <!--dependency id="cordova-plugin-file" version="^4.0.0" />
    <dependency id="cordova-plugin-compat" version="^1.0.0" /-->
```

Of course I needed to do the same process (download localy and edit plugin.xml file) for the plugin describe in the dependency tag.

Then I've installed the plugin from my local path and it worked (like:  cordova plugin add "myPath/cordova-plugin-media").

Answer (score -1):

there  is possibility that u r using some secure internet line (like company network ) which causing problem try some other network

Comment: this should be comment not answer